# Accelerated observer and a free falling particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity

I'm doing excercise 13.14 from the book Gravitation of MTW. In this excercise an accelerated observer studies the path of a freely falling particle as it passes through the origin of the reference frame of the accelerated observer. The velocity of the particle is given by

$$\mathbf{v} = \frac{dx^{\hat{j}}}{dx^{\hat{0}}}\,\mathbf{e_{\hat{j}}} $$

where the indices with hats correspond to the coordinates of the accelerated observer with the basis given by the tetrad that has been fermi-walker transported (and rotated) from an original inertial frame.

In the excercise it must me proven that the acceleration of this particle is given by

$$\frac{d^2 x^{\hat{j}}}{dx^{\hat{0}2}} \mathbf{e_{\hat{j}}} = -\mathbf{a}-2\omega \times \mathbf{v} + 2(\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{v})\mathbf{v}   $$

I've started as suggested in the excercise by taking the geodesic equation:

$$\frac{d^{2}x^{\hat{j}}}{dx^{\hat{0}2}}= -\Gamma^{\hat{j}}_{\hat{\beta}\hat{\gamma}} \frac{dx^{\hat{\beta}}}{dx^{\hat{0}}}  \frac{dx^{\hat{\gamma}}}{dx^{\hat{0}}}$$

And then, using the conection coefficients calculated at the previous section I arrive at

$$\frac{d^{2}x^{\hat{j}}}{dx^{\hat{0}2}} = -a^{\hat{j}} - 2\omega^{\hat{j}}v^{\hat{k}}\epsilon_{\hat{0}\hat{i}\hat{j}\hat{k}}  - \Gamma^{\hat{j}}_{\hat{k}\hat{l}} \frac{dx^{\hat{k}}}{dx^{\hat{0}}}  \frac{dx^{\hat{l}}}{dx^{\hat{0}}}  $$

I haven't been able to make the last term appear. How can I make it appear?